# To what extent were civilians targeted in the conflict/war in Donbass in 2014-2022?

Tags: armed-conflict, ukraine, donbass

The conflict/war in the Donbass (the parts of the Donetsk and Luhansk oblasts of Ukraine in which pro-Russian separatists have declared independence) has cost several thousands of civilian lives from 2014 to 2022.

However, [reports on various kinds of casualties seem to conflict among sources](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casualties_of_the_Russo-Ukrainian_War#Deaths_by_regions), and of course there is the question of intent vs. "collateral" damage. I have also heard several allegations of intentional targeting of residential areas in Donetsk and perhaps elsewhere by the Ukrainian military, several years back (perhaps in 2014).

To what extent / in what ways did the parties in that conflict actually target civilians, over the years?

Note: I'm asking about the period between 2014 and the Russian invasion of Feb 2022.

Comment: By no means an answer, but here is a video from a year ago where people talk about it on the street. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2bNzjBJF_G0&t=872s I have linked to where the "interview" starts

Comment: Not my DV, but I'm not sure how you'd expect us to solve this narrative conflict between what Russia (and their LPD/DPR proxy) claims and what the Ukrainians claim.

Comment: @Fizz: I was hoping that someone following these matters more closely in recent years could overview what they know based on what they've read and heard. I didn't ask about whose fault is it, and is it excusable etc.

Comment: Related: [Do the republics of Donetsk and Luhansk consider themselves bound by the Geneva Conventions?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/73606/28554)

Comment: @Thomas Koelle There are a lot of similar videos from the other side blaming Ukraine.

Comment: Would the shooting down of Malaysian Airlines flight 17 over the Donbass would be such a case?

Comment: @Trilarion: 1. That plane is a third party, so I think that's out-of-scope 2. Wasn't there a dispute regarding who downed the plane?

Comment: @einpoklum Regardless of who targeted it, surely someone from there targeted it and while the plane was a third party, there were civilians on it. Did you only ask for Russian or Ukrainian civilians deaths?

Comment: @Trilarion: Yes, I mostly meant targeting the other side's civilians.

Comment: @convert I think your comment indicate that the interview I linked is biased against Russia. That was not the intention of the link. If you have other interviews that resemble my link, but you think are sided the other way feel free to give a link.

Comment: @Thomas Koelle Have not said that it´s biased, just a bit onesided, but thats normal during a war.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this [long post about the state of monitoring](https://zen.yandex.ru/media/discoursio/chto-nujno-znat-pro-eti-vosem-let-na-donbasse-analiz-otchetov-monitoringovoi-missii-obse-za-20142021-gody-62455c32c115dc2050a83705) since 2014 (press translate)

Highlights include:

> The 2016 report states that from 1 January to 31 December, the SMM documented 442 civilian casualties in the conflict zone — 88 civilian deaths (22 women, 58 men, one girl under 2 years of age, five boys and two adults whose gender has not been determined) and 354 wounded. Most of the cases (281 out of 442) occurred in the DPR and LPR.

> Local residents of settlements on both sides of the contact line told OSCE members that they often saw mobile firing positions in their residential areas (so close that they could see flashes from the use of weapons):

One of the first notable incidents is [bombing of Lugansk city hall on Jun 2, 2014](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B0%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80_%D0%BF%D0%BE_%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8E_%D0%9B%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8). An air strike by two Ukrainian military planes left 8 dead, 28 wounded.

Comment: It's not clear to me that bombing the city hall (while of questionable military use) is a clear indication of targeting civilians. Russia has also bombed some governor buildings in the more recent conflict. [Kharkiv](https://www.aa.com.tr/en/russia-ukraine-crisis/russian-forces-hit-governors-building-in-ukraines-kharkiv-with-missile/2519526) ; [Mykolaiv](https://www.businessinsider.com/video-captures-russian-missile-seconds-before-hitting-government-building-2022-3) etc.

Comment: Related Q here on that https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/73337/why-dont-attackers-in-war-target-government-buildings-as-much-as-they-could

Comment: The Russian wikipedia article you linked to even says that "The leadership of the LNR calls the purpose of the airstrike an attempted assassination of the head of the Lugansk People's Republic, Valery Bolotov , and his entourage, who at that moment were in the building". That unfortunately make the target even more valid and the civilians who died "collateral damage".

Comment: It's also worth recalling that the US bombed several of Saddam's palaces in the two Gulf wars, trying to get him personally.

Comment: @Fizz I'm not sure that Saddam's palaces were publicly accessible, whereas town hall is usually situated downtown. It is debatable whether head of civil administration is a valid military target.

Comment: ... and even houses in busy neighborhoods, where they thought he might be hiding. https://abcnews.go.com/GMA/story?id=125232&page=1